# Understanding resource values in Android

Tags: android

I may be twisting things because my last programming was Windows in C.  But am trying to find "where" in android apps a resource such as an icon is assigned a value and where it's referenced in code.

Am doing my best to find it now, but can't.

Maybe I am misunderstanding the way "resources" work in Android?

Thanks ahead,

Sergio

Comment: If you have created a new blank activity then you can res folder containing drawable values layout

Answer (score 1):

When you compile your app, a class called "R" is generated. This references all your resources (strings, drawables, layouts, ...). Each resource is assigned an integer value.

In code, you would reference that resource through the "R" class, for instance:

```
Image: R.drawable.my_drawable
String: R.string.hello_world
Layout: R.layout.my_layout
```

and so on. As a concrete example, you would have

```
String text = getString(R.string.hello_world);
```

Comment: Thank, found the file.  Am still a little lost. So I found the value of the "launcher" icon.  Yet I cannot find where that value is tied to the icon.

The problem that made me ask this question was that the launcher icon stayed as a default.  So from my old programming environment I would look for the file that basically says "path/launcher.png = 0x01"

So am now even more lost as I find that "ic_launcher" is in TWO classes, "mipmap" and "drawable", both with different values.  Yet I wouldn't know where to backtrack in my app where the icon is called from (which class, which value, etc.)

Comment: I'm not certain I follow. The R class is generated at compile time, as developers we don't care what value something has been assigned, we just need a way to reference it. That's what the R class is for, your resources are packaged in your APK and the R class is your means to reference them. How that happens at run time is not relevant. What exactly are you after that you need to know how the values are generated?

Comment: Maybe I am thinking of something that no longer exists.  I guess I am lost in finding WHERE it's referenced.